# unicode characters error for list item button in kivy

Tags: python, unicode, kivy, listitem, persian

I've created a list item button in kivy and use arabic reshaper for writing persian for each button text but when i click buttons in list App return error and break while it should change the screen.
here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton, ListItemLabel
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty
from Poem import PoemsName, TrName
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import arabic_reshaper

class MenuButton(ListItemButton):
    index = NumericProperty(0)

class PageText(ListItemLabel):
    index = NumericProperty(0)

class MenuPage(Screen):

    def args_converter(self, row_index, title):
        print ("{0}".format(row_index))

        return {
            'index': row_index,
            'text': get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(title))
            #'text': title
        }

class Page(Screen): 

    def test(self):
        return ['line number #%i' %i for i in range(10)]

    def args_converter(self, row_index, title):
        return {
            'index': row_index,
            'text': title
            }

class myApp(App):
    data = ListProperty(["%s" %TrName[i] for i in PoemsName])

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
        menu = MenuPage(name='menu')
        sm.add_widget(menu)
        for i in PoemsName:
            sm.add_widget(Page(name=i))
        return sm

    def on_menu_selection(self, index):
        self.root.current = PoemsName[index]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

and the .kv file :

```
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter
#:import factory kivy.factory

<MenuButton>:
    size_hint_y: None
    deselected_color: (1,1,0,1)
    selected_color: (1,1,0,1)
    height: dp(65)
    color: 0.1,1,0.5,1 
    on_press: app.on_menu_selection(self.index)
    font_name: 'data/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'
    font_size: '20dp'

<PageText>:
    size_hint_y:None
    height: dp(65)
    font_size: 40
    color: 0.66,0.06,0.06,1

<MenuPage>:
    BoxLayout:  
        ListView:
            size_hint: (1,.95)
            adapter:
                la.ListAdapter(
                data=app.data,
                cls=factory.Factory.MenuButton,
                selection_mode='single',
                allow_empty_selection=True,
                args_converter=root.args_converter)
<Page>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Image:
            source:'header/%s.png' %root.name
            size_hint:(1,0.25)
        ListView:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,0,0.5
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
            size_hint: (1, 1)
            adapter:
                la.ListAdapter(
                data=root.test(),
                cls=factory.Factory.PageText,
                args_converter=root.args_converter)
```

and insdide the Poem.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

PoemsName = ['No1','No2', 'No3', 'No4']

TrName = {'No1':u'نام اول' ,'No2':u'نام دوم' , 'No3':u'نام سوم' , 'No4':u'نام چهارم'}
```

and the error is some thing like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\python\persian-menu-test\select2.py", line 55, in
 <module>
     myApp().run()
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\app.py", line 792, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\base.py", line 481, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\core\window\window_pygame.py", line 381, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\core\window\window_pygame.py", line 287, in _mainloop

     EventLoop.idle()
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\base.py", line 324, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\base.py", line 309, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\base.py", line 220, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4409)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 649, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4409)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 675, in on_touch_up
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4409)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1002, in on_touch_up
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 306, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4409)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 219, in on_touch_up
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 306, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4409)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 306, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4409)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 306, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4409)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 697, in on_touch_up
     self.simulate_touch_down(touch)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\scrollview.py", line 508, in simulate_touch_down
     ret = super(ScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 284, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4409)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 284, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4409)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\behaviors.py", line 92, in on_touch_down
     self._do_press()
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\behaviors.py", line 75, in _do_press
     self.state = 'down'
   File "properties.pyx", line 345, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy\properties.c:3524)
   File "properties.pyx", line 377, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy\properties.c:3979)
   File "properties.pyx", line 431, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy\properties.c:4547)
   File "D:\kivy\kivy\kivy\lang.py", line 1317, in call_fn
 element, key, value, rule.value))
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 17-19: or
dinal not in range(128)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What is the traceback of the error you encounter?

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 17-19: or
dinal not in range(128)

Comment: button in the other part of program are working properly but it return error in list

Comment: Please edit the full traceback (not just that line) into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v found the answer
unicode characters shoud endcode in python code:

args_converter in MenuPAge class should change like this:

class MenuPage(Screen):

```
def args_converter(self, row_index, title):
    #print ("{0}".format(row_index))
    text = get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(title))
    return {
        'index': row_index,
        'text': text.unicode('utf-8')
        #'text': title
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this a bit late. But I've just ran into the same issue, and I'll add the resolution here, just in case someone else encounters this.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3078) with the people from kivy. It turns out that this has been fixed in the latest dev version. Also running the app with the `-O` flag will bypass this error.

Comment: actually both not worked, in kivy 1.9.0 the problem is still alive and -O is not true flag. are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure. The traceback points to that line https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/1.8.0/kivy/lang.py#L1317 

As you can see there if __debug__ is not set to True, it will not call that line. If tested my case against 1.9.0-dev and the problem does not occur. Anyway, this is/was still a bug in kivy and you should ask them for more help. 

Hope this helps!